# running an (html/javascript) webpage from inside a visual basic.net program

Tags: vb.net, google-maps

i wrote a (visual basic.net-2008) desktop app that allows ham radio operators to enter a call, 
such as WA0H, and the program gives the ham's location (springfield, mo.).

you can download the program free from my website .. www.wa0h.com

i want the program to display the ham's location on a google map using google's api-v3.

i have created an (html/javascript) webpage, where you enter the location in a form box, 
click a (find) button, and the app displays the map ok, including a marker pin on the map.

??? how do i run the (webpage) from inside my (vb.net) program ???

my vb.net program needs to:
1 .. pass the address to the webpage
2 .. click the webpage (find) button

according to the google maps (developers) website, they want questions posted to stackoverflow.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1-First you need to create pin on the map 
i suggest using Google Static Maps API as in hear : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#quick_example

for the example use this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

then you get something like this

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&key=AIzaSyDnw6k3UjE2qZ5nLnI8cKghaEEdCXV0PUI&signature=5xiF2jgoXwFonsjew0PmtZdSTHU=
```

2-you need to open this page using web browser.

to use "WebBrowser" inside of toolbox, drag and drop it then set ScriptErrorsSuppressed to true

to set webbrowser url you can use `webbrowser1.navigate("your url as string")`

Comment: hi Mahdi .. I am using .. webbrowser1.documenttext = MyHtmlJsString .. to display my webpage .. but nothing happens because I need to pass the webpage the location I want displayed.

Comment: do like i said and set its url to what ever you want

Comment: sorry its navigate for set url of webbrowser